Create a DAX Measure that Calculates the Difference Between Various Portfolio Holding Weights and that of a Reference Portfolio
I would appreciate assistance in creating a DAX Measure that calculates the difference in security weights of several portfolios relative to a reference portfolio (which is one of the portfolios being evaluated and selected through a slicer.). The end-use will be able to select which portfolio they want as the reference portfolio.
I have a data (Fact) table called "Holdings" that has the following fields:  Date, Portfolio Name, Security Ticker, and Portfolio Weight.
There are three lookup (DIM) tables linked to the "Holdings" table, but I believe I only need the Calendar Table for this specific scenario:  Calendar Table, Security, and Portfolio Name.
If I choose "Portfolio A" in the Slicer, I would like to see the following for each security:

For Portfolio A:  Portfolio A weight of that security minus Portfolio
A weight of that security
For Portfolio B:  Portfolio B weight of that security minus Portfolio
A weight of that security
For Portfolio C:  Portfolio C weight of that security minus Portfolio
A weight of that security etc.

Holdings Table :
DATE    PORTFOLIO   SECURITY  WEIGHT
1/31/24 Portfolio A IBM       0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio A APPL      0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio A MSFT      0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio A C         0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio B IBM       0.15
1/31/24 Portfolio B APPL      0.35
1/31/24 Portfolio B MSFT      0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio B C         0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio C IBM       0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio C APPL      0.15
1/31/24 Portfolio C MSFT      0.35
1/31/24 Portfolio C C         0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio D IBM       -
1/31/24 Portfolio D APPL      0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio D MSFT      0.50
1/31/24 Portfolio D C         0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio E IBM       0.25
1/31/24 Portfolio E APPL      0.35
1/31/24 Portfolio E MSFT      0.15
1/31/24 Portfolio E C         0.25

Table Summarizing the Holding Weights :
PORTFOLIO   IBM     APPL    MSFT    C
Portfolio A 0.25    0.25    0.25    0.25
Portfolio B 0.15    0.35    0.25    0.25
Portfolio C 0.25    0.15    0.35    0.25
Portfolio D -       0.25    0.50    0.25
Portfolio E 0.25    0.35    0.15    0.25

What I want to display as a matrix table in Power BI :
Difference between Portfolio and Reference Portfolio :
PORTFOLIO   IBM    APPL     MSFT    C
Portfolio A   -     -         -     -
Portfolio B (0.10) 0.10       -     -
Portfolio C   -   (0.10)    0.10    -
Portfolio D (0.25)   -      0.25    -
Portfolio E   -    0.10    (0.10)   -

Additional Information:
In the original post, I changed the weight of Microsoft in Portfolio C enter code here to be 0.35 so that it foots to 100.
In the model, I have four measures:
'Security Weight = SUM(Holdings[Weight])'

`Selected Portfolio = SELECTEDVALUE(Holdings[PORTFOLIO])`

'Reference Portfolio (SELECTED) = 
CALCULATE(
[Security Weight],
FILTER(Holdings, Holdings[PORTFOLIO] = [Selected Portfolio]))'

'Weight Difference = [Security Weight] - 
[Reference Portfolio(SELECTED)]'

The Matrix table is set up as follows:
'Rows: Holdings[PORTFOLIO]'
'Columns:  Holdings[SECURITY]'
'Values:  [Weight Difference]'

When I set the matrix table up using the "Weight Difference" measure and select a reference portfolio through the Slicer, the table only returns that particular portfolio (collapsing to a single row) and returns the security weights; not the difference.  For Example, if I choose Portfolio B in the Slicer to be the reference portfolio, it only shows Portfolio B and returns its actual weights, not the weight of the portfolio minus the weight of the reference portfolio.

Can you provide a clear scenario with input and output ?

First create a new table for all the distinct portfolio values:
Portfolios = DISTINCT(Holdings[PORTFOLIO])

This table will be used as your slicer.
Then try this measure:
Measure = 

VAR thisPortfolio = SELECTEDVALUE(Holdings[PORTFOLIO])
VAR thisSecurity = SELECTEDVALUE(Holdings[SECURITY])
VAR thisWeight = SELECTEDVALUE(Holdings[WEIGHT])

VAR selectedPortfolio = SELECTEDVALUE(Portfolios[PORTFOLIO])

VAR weightPortA = CALCULATE(
                    MINX(Holdings, [WEIGHT])
                    , FILTER(ALL(Holdings)
                        , Holdings[PORTFOLIO] = selectedPortfolio
                        && Holdings[SECURITY] = thisSecurity
                        )
    ) + 0

VAR diff = thisWeight - weightPortA

RETURN diff

Output example 1:

Output example 2:


Is there a way to enhance the Measure so that it calculates based on the Slicer input (Portfolio A/Portfolio B/Portfolio C, etc.) rather than a hard-coded "Portfolio A"?  The user wants to be able to change which portfolio is the reference.
I've tried using the SELECTEDVALUE function but all values come up zero.  Plus when I select a specific portfolio in the slicer to be the reference portfolio, the matrix table only returns the portfolio that was selected in the slicer.

Thank you Nick!  The updated code performed exactly as needed.
